# Why <HF,⊆> is simply isomorphic to the lattice of finite subsets of a countable set, such as the collection of finite subsets of N under inclusion.

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

<[image]
<HF,⊆> is simply isomorphic to
the lattice of finite subsets of a countable set, such as the collection of
finite subsets of N under inclusion.
why?Can we have <HF,⊆> is simply isomorphic to finite subsets of N under devide relation <= to <N,|>

Comment: Please edit your Question to put more context around the problem that you pose.  Set up the problem, defining the set $\mathbf{HF}$ of hereditarily finite sets.  Identify the text from which you are quoting (title and author, perhaps the year of publicaton).  Explain where the problem has gotten difficult for you.  It will be easier for future Readers to respond (and benefit from your posts) if you add this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a countable set, and let $[X]^{<\omega}$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$. Consider a bijection $f: X\rightarrow HF$. This bijection induces a map $$\hat{f}: [X]^{<\omega}\rightarrow [HF]^{<\omega}$$ given by $$A\mapsto \{f(a): a\in A\}.$$ Moreover, $\hat{f}$ "doesn't change subsethood" in the sense that $$A\subseteq B\iff \hat{f}(A)\subseteq \hat{f}(B)$$ for all $A,B\in[X]^{<\omega}$. Put another way, $\hat{f}$ is an isomorphism between the structures $([X]^{<\omega},\subseteq)$ and $([HF]^{<\omega},\subseteq)$.

- *Note that $\hat{f}$ is just a restriction to finite subsets of the usual function $\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(HF)$ induced by $f$.*

But here's the cute bit: it turns out that $HF=[HF]^{<\omega}$. This may look weird at first and it's certainly not true that $X=[X]^{<\omega}$ in general - it's a special feature of $HF$. So we have in fact $$([X]^{<\omega},\subseteq)\cong([HF]^{<\omega},\subseteq)=(HF,\subseteq).$$ (That "$=$" instead of "$\cong$" isn't a typo, they are literally the same object.)

Comment: Ugh. I was literally with my finger over the "post your answer" button.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Mwahahaha!

Comment: You win this round, Dr. Schweber!